# How do I use a layer of Bing / Google a "WebApplication" in "ArcGIS Server Manager"?

Tags: arcgis-server, google-maps, bing-maps

I'm using "ArcGIS Server."
I want to publish a "WebApplication". 
I created a map of my city. 
I want to have as the background world map with satellite images of "BingMaps" or "GoogleMaps" or "ArcGIS World Map free".
See the image below. I tried it. But it bring to me this error: "Unable to add layer. Request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation Failed."

https://sites.google.com/site/christiancrca/erro%20BING%20maps%20Arcgis%20Christian%20Rogerio.jpg

Any idea about how to use as background a service of image satellite maps with my map?

[image: Error Status HTTP 417]

Comment: Do you have the license for Bing Maps for ArcGIS Server? (if below version 10)

Comment: I have the version 10. I solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Craig.

I fixed the error HTTP 417. I add this lines on web.config:

> < configuration>
>      <  configSections>
>      < /configSections>
>      < system.net>
>      < settings>
>          < servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
>      < /settings>
>      < /system.net>
>   < /configuration>

I added these lines in "web.config" application "iis / arcgis / manager" and in the my new "WebApplication".

More information: http://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/the-request-failed-with-http-status-417-expectation-failed/

Note: I put spaces in the html tags, of the block code, to appear in this post.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you using for your web applications (javascript, flex, silverlight)?

If using Javascript, consider [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/widget_basemap.html)

If silverlight, consider [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/silverlight-api/)

if flex, consider [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-api/)

In any event, you may want to stay away from actually adding the imagery to your service as you can just reference ESRI basemaps to do the work for you (they aren't exactly google or bing but they do the deed, imo). If you start adding your own imagery you will need to get acquainted with caching, and depending on your server space, you could be in for a treat.

Comment: on behalf of the OP: none. these Web Applications in AGS are pre-packaged Web ADF sites. That's why they're such a pain to manage