# How to create pre-configured tags for new ASP.NET Web Applications?

Tags: arcgis-server, asp.net

I'm using the "ArcGIS Server Manager" to create "Web Applications" with my maps. In ASP.NET project has a "web.config". How do I get my "web.config" come with some "tags" standard?

More specifically, these tags would be:

> > < configuration> < configSections> < /configSections> < system.net> < settings> < >>servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" /> < /settings> < /system.net> < >>/configuration>

These tags are described in:
[How do I use a layer of Bing / Google a "WebApplication" in "ArcGIS Server Manager"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35340/how-do-i-use-a-layer-of-bing-google-a-webapplication-in-arcgis-server-manag)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I managed to bring my Web.config file with my default tags, when I create a new Web Application.

I changed the file:

> > C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ArcGIS\Manager\Modules\Applications\Templates\mv_cs\web.config

Hint: make a backup before, and put in the same directory.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you please hit the green tick next to this answer.  It lets the community know that this Q is solved.  Thanks for sharing how you solved it.